# Why does the round up function in Pandas is not working?

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried different ways to round up the Price values in my dataframe to 2 decimal places and they're not working. Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Items': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'Price1': ['235.46548', '351.2456', '481.9874', '169.846'],
        'Price2': ['256.00', '584.951', '438.856', '246.285']}


price_data = pd.DataFrame(data)


decimals = pd.Series([2, 2], index=['Price1', 'Price2'])
price_data.round(decimals)
```

I also tried the below code:

```
cols = ['Price1', 'Price2']

price_data.loc[:, cols] = price_data[cols].round(2)
```

Both methods give me the below output in which the values have not been rounded up:

```
  Items     Price1   Price2
0     a  235.46548   256.00
1     b   351.2456  584.951
2     c   481.9874  438.856
3     d    169.846  246.285
```

Comment: Your price columns are of type string. Is this accurate to your dataset or is this a copy error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type of your number is `string`, you need to use `astype('float64')` like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Items': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'Price1': ['235.46548', '351.2456', '481.9874', '169.846'],
        'Price2': ['256.00', '584.951', '438.856', '246.285']}


price_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

cols = ['Price1', 'Price2']

price_data.loc[:, cols] = price_data[cols].astype('float64').round(2)
```

Output:

```
    Items   Price1  Price2
0   a      235.47   256.0
1   b      351.25   584.95
2   c      481.99   438.86
3   d      169.85   246.28
```